# js code shift or transformer from jQuery to native?

Tags: javascript, jquery, abstract-syntax-tree, jscodeshift

So if I would need to change code like this:

```
var amazed = $(['foo', 'bar']).map(function(i, el){
  return this + '!';
});
```

into Native like

```
var amazed = (['foo', 'bar']).map(function(el, i){
  return el + '!';
});
```

I can do something like (https://astexplorer.net/#/0rIHMowCQf)

```
  return j(file.source)
    .find(j.Identifier).filter(ident => {
    if (ident.node.name == '$') console.log(ident);
    return ident.node.name == '$';
  }).replaceWith('').toSource();
```

as a first step and that will delete the jQuery `$` sign and just leave a `()` which can work, but feels like I am cheating since I am just giving a empty Identifier to the CallExpression. I still have to discover how to replace the order of the arguments.

Can js code shift be used for such cases, like transforming jQuery to Native, and eventually just:

```
var amazed = ['foo', 'bar'].map(function(el, i){
  return el + '!';
});
```

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I'd be wary of using something like this without static analysis tooling.

Comment: @Paarth check out the great answer under, nice tool!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can absolute use jscodeshift for this. Just be aware of the limitations:

- Not every identifier `$` might refer to jQuery.
- There might be calls to jQuery's `.map` function that look like

  ```
  var foo = $(['foo', 'bar']);
  foo.map(...);
  ```

  which you probably won't be able to catch.

However, these might not be issues in your code base. Writing generic codemods is hard(er). Writing one that works for your specific codebase is easier.

I would to the following:

Find all `CallExpression`'s whose `callee` is a `MemberExpression` *and* that `MemberExpression` has `map` as its property and `$(...)` as its object. You can also verify that the argument passed to `$` is an array literal. That would again have the limitation that it wouldn't consider `var foo = []; $(foo);`.

Then you can replace the the "inner" `CallExpression` with its argument. Replacing the function parameters of the callback is simply to.

All of that together. All the checks are optional. The less strict the tests are, the more use cases you can cover, but the possibility for getting false positives will also be larger.

```
  return j(file.source)
    .find(j.CallExpression, {
      callee: {
        property: {
          name: 'map'
        },
        // verify that we call map on $(...)
        object: {
           callee: {
             name: '$',
           },
           // verify that the argument is an array literal
           arguments: {
             0: {
               type: 'ArrayExpression'
             }
           },
        }
      },
    })
    .forEach(path => {
        const jQueryArgument = path.node.callee.object.arguments[0];
        // replace "inner" CallExpression with argument
        path.node.callee.object = jQueryArgument;

        // switch callback arguments
        var callback = path.node.arguments[0];
        callback.params.reverse();
    })
    .toSource();
```

https://astexplorer.net/#/kQICtMfd89

Comment: Nice! The explanation made me understand soo much more, thanks! There was a missing part: Renaming jQuery's `this` inside the return, but with your explanation I nailed it myself: https://astexplorer.net/#/kQICtMfd89/1 (thank you again!)

Comment: Oops, yeah I missed that. Glad you figured it out :)